# Use variable's value to get another variable

Tags: bash, terminal

In bash how can I use a variable's value to reference another variable?

e.g. my best attempt so far (which is the same as `say -v es`):

```
learning="es"
es="Jorge"
say -v $learning "Hola, me llamo Jorge"
```

How do I make it equivalent to `say -v Jorge`?

---

## EDIT:

This has been closed as a duplicate, but I do not find the "duplicate" question useful at all. The answers there show how to set variables. I want to know how I can use them.

Comment: consider using associative arrays instead…

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf i didn't know bash had those. sounds like that would be a much better solution, rather than what I have atm: a whole file with a list of variable declarations xD

Comment: The solution is `say -v "${!learning}"`